# Installing miniconda for theano with gpuarray: as root or as user?

Tags: python, conda

I've always used virtualenv(wrapper) for my python needs, but now I'm considering trying conda for new projects, mainly because theano docs "*strongly*" recommend it, and hoping that it will save me some hassle with pygpu config. I'm on linux mint 16( I guess, kernel in uname is from ubuntu 14.04) and there are no system packages for conda/miniconda so I'll have to use their shell script for installation.

Now I have a dilemma - should I install as my user or as root? What is likely to give me less hassle in the future (given that I'm going to use (nvidia) GPU for computation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anaconda and miniconda are designed to be installed by each user individually, into each users `$HOME/miniconda` directory. If you installed it as a shared install as root, all users would need to access `/root/miniconda`.

Also, environments will be created in `$HOME/miniconda/envs`, so environments of several people will interfere with each other (plus the whole issue of permissions, file ownership etc.).

Bottom line: Don't install it as root, install it as yourself.

Any third party dependencies you'd still install as root using `apt-get`, but once they're installed they're accessible by everyone, no matter if they use miniconda or not.